# Javascript Caesars Cipher algorithm code break down needed?

Tags: javascript

I am a freecodecamp camper. And I need a help to understand how does the below code works which is an advanced solution.

```js
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, L => String.fromCharCode((L.charCodeAt(0) % 26) + 65));
}

// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(rot13("AAA !"));
```

I do have a little idea on why we are using modulus 26 and then adding 65. but I dont understand what L=> is actually doing. I also understand a bit of regular expression. Please break down this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L =>` declares an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is a shorthand syntax for:

```
function(L) {
    return String.fromCharCode((L.charCodeAt(0) % 26) + 65));
}
```

When you use a function as the replacement argument in `String.prototype.replace()`, it gets called on each match of the regular expression, and the return value is used as the replacement.

So the regular expression matches each uppercase letter in `str`. It calls that function, which calculates the new character code using modulus and addition, converts it back to a character, and that returned character becomes the replacement.

However, the function won't work as written -- it needs to return the result of `str.replace()`.

```js
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  return str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, L => String.fromCharCode((L.charCodeAt(0) % 26) + 65));
}

// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(rot13("ABMNTZ !"));
```

Comment: Looks like there's something missing here: `which calculates the new character code by ,`